# Setting formatted value breaks function

Tags: javascript

I've got this function to modify a string to a USD-like format

```js
function formatAmount(el){
  var val    = el.value;

  //Only Numbers
  val = val.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');

  // Pad with Zeros
  val = val.padStart(3,0);
  
  // Value with Period
  val = val.slice(0, -2) + '.' + val.slice(-2);
  
  // Append $
  val = '$' + val;
  
  console.log( val );
  //el.value = val; // Breaks??
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="formatAmount(this);" />
```

When formatting the value, it works just fine: Typing `12345` into the input will log `$123.45`. As soon as I change the value with `el.value = val;`, the function seems to get a little weird, and I can't quite figure out why. `12345` now returns `$0123.45` if you type fast or `$00123.45` if you type slowly. Why is is appending the 0's to the string when changing the field value, but not when logging it without changing?

---

*Edit:*

Based on what @Dennis mentioned, wrapping it in a typing-timeout function seems to work, as long as the timeout is sufficiently high. `10ms` doesn't work, but `100ms` seems to? This doesn't seem very elegant, however:

```
var formatTimeout = null;

function formatAmount(el){
    clearTimeout(formatTimeout);
    formatTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        var val     = el.value;

        //Only Numbers
        val = val.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');

        // Pad with Zeros
        val = val.padStart(3,0);

        // Value with Period
        val = val.slice(0, -2) + '.' + val.slice(-2);

        // Append $
        val = '$' + val;

        //console.log( val );
        el.value = val; // Breaks??
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: That happens because you add `0` padding and never remove it when the function is called and the input contains a formatted value.

Comment: Google `debounce Javascript`. Also, I'd strongly recommend to only format the number on `blur`. Why are you not using `Intl.prototype.formatNumber()`?

Comment: In this particular application I need the number formatted from right to left as it's typed in. I looked at using the Intl format but it doesn't seem to play with with cents, and many of these formats require small amounts in cents. It seems viable enough for what I need to check the string for the added 0s and trim them before padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function gets triggered at every key press.

If you type in 12345, it will get triggered 5 times.
Here's what your value will look like if typing sufficiently slowly:

```
1, the function will change it to $0.01
2, it gets added at the end of the existing string to make it $0.012, which gets formatted by the function as $00.12
3, the initial string will be $00.123, and it will get formatted as $001.23.
...
```

The final result will be $00123.45.

There are a few ways to deal with this problem. The simplest solution would be to trim the initial 0s to keep your number clean, right before padding with zeros.

Comment: I was checking the length of the string before the 0's but that wasn't working. So I decided to check for and strip the 0's before the padding like you mentioned and it seems to be working just like I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This difference between results while `console.log` and actually assigning the value is because the input to the `formatAmount` function is different each time.

When you set the value of the input field, this is what happens;

```
-> User enter `1`
-> formatAmount takes the value, converts it to $0.01 and *sets the value* to the input box
-> user enter `2`
-> formatAmount takes the value ($0.012), converts it to $00.12 and *sets the value* to the input box
```

This continues until you finish `12345` and get $00123.45. This happens because the two `0`s you added in the start never vanish after the first `1` is typed.

Also, `console.log` works fine because everytime, the value received is `1`, `12`,...`12345`. The logic works fine for these. Only fails when you set the value back

Answer (score 0):

A keyup action in javascript seems to work fine. Tested with various speeds and works like a charm. Also, try pasting numbers and use regex to remove leading 0's like

```js
var textInput = document.getElementById('hello');
textInput.onkeyup = function (e) {
    formatAmount(textInput.value);
};

function formatAmount(el){
  var val    = el;

  //Only Numbers
  val = val.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');

  // Pad with Zeros
  val = val.padStart(3,0);
  // replace leading 0's 
  val = val.replace(/^0+/, '');
  // Value with Period
  val = val.slice(0, -2) + '.' + val.slice(-2);
  
  // Append $
  val = '$' + val;
  
  textInput.value = val;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="hello" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show an alternative starting point using `Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.format()`. Feel free to adjust to your requirements.

```js
function formatAmount(el){
  el.value = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD', minimumIntegerDigits: 3 }).format(parseFloat(el.value.indexOf('$') === 0 ? el.value.substr(1) : el.value));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="formatAmount(this);" />
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that your function is being executed multiple times at the same time, the first execution is not even finished before the next one starts. You need to check if the function is already running.